# Is this proof for pseudo primes suitable?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, pseudoprimes

Given that $$ab\equiv 1 \pmod n$$

and $n$ is a pseudo prime base $a$,

Show that $b$ is also a base for pseudo prime n.

I can raise to the power of $n$: $$(ab)^{n}\equiv 1 \pmod n$$

$$a^{n}{b}^{n}\equiv 1 \pmod n$$

and now I to divide them both by $ab$ which is equivalent 1.

Then I get $$ab(a^{n-1}{b}^{n-1})\equiv 1 \pmod n$$

$$a^{n-1}{b}^{n-1}\equiv 1 \pmod n$$

and $a^{n-1}\equiv 1 \pmod n$ by Fermat's Little Theorem. Then $b^{n-1}$ is congruent $1$ modulo $n$ which suits Fermat's Theorem...

though I am not realy sure of my proof...

Comment: I am sure.  The numbers $a$ and $b$ must belong to a multiplicative subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, so your operations are valid.

Comment: @OscarLanzi thanks for the feedback

Comment: Why do you rise to $n$ instead of $n-1$ in the first step?

Comment: @user6394019 The congruence $$a^{n-1}\equiv 1\mod n$$ holds because $n$ is a base-a-pseudoprime. You cannot use the argument with Fermat's little theorem because $n$ is composite. Probably you mean the "Fermat-congruence" that is saitisfied by pseudoprimes.